# jquery hiding an array of id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a bookmarklet that will hide all data-agentid selectors that have a data-color selector = 30. so I have a list on the website that look something like this

```
<div class="sch" data-agent-id=1></div>
         <div data-agentid="1" data-color="30">
         <div data-agentid="1" data-color="20">
         ...
<div class="sch" data-agent-id=2></div>
         <div data-agentid="2" data-color="10">
         <div data-agentid="2" data-color="20">
         ...
...
edited
```

There is a lot more code but I figure this is the important part.
I am thinking I can just build an array of ids where their color is 30 and then hide all of the ids in the array. My code is below but I don't think it is even building the array at this point.

```
(function() {
  var arr = $('*[data-color="30"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).data("data-agentid");
  }).get().join();
  $('*[data-agent-id=arr]').hide();
})();
```

Comment: Well you are looking for `<div data-agentid="arr">` with your code

Comment: Are the data-agentid's on elements that are not with data-color???? Or are you trying to reselect the elements you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no selector that works off an array. So you would need to make a comma separated value

```js
var selector = $('[data-color="30"]').map(function() {
  return '[data-agent-id="' + $(this).data("agentid") + '"]';
}).get().join(',');

$(selector).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30"></div>
<div data-agentid="2" data-color="20"></div>
<div data-agentid="3" data-color="30"></div>


<div data-agent-id="1">1-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="1">1-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="1">1-3</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-3</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-3</div>
```

Other option is to use filter()

```js
var ids = $('[data-color="30"]').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('agentid');
}).get();

$('[data-agent-id]')
  .filter(function () {
    return ids.includes($(this).data('agent-id'));
  })
  .hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30"></div>
<div data-agentid="2" data-color="20"></div>
<div data-agentid="3" data-color="30"></div>


<div data-agent-id="1">1-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="1">1-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="1">1-3</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-3</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-3</div>
```

Or just select in a loop

```js
$('[data-color="30"]').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('agentid');
  $('[data-agent-id="' + id + '"]').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30"></div>
<div data-agentid="2" data-color="20"></div>
<div data-agentid="3" data-color="30"></div>


<div data-agent-id="1">1-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-1</div>
<div data-agent-id="1">1-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-2</div>
<div data-agent-id="1">1-3</div>
<div data-agent-id="2">2-3</div>
<div data-agent-id="3">3-3</div>
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you would just do this directly:

```js
$('[data-color="30"]').hide()
```

---

Edit: Now that you've clarified what you're trying to do, it'll be more performant to select the elements once and iterate over them calling `hide` on the matching ones:

```js
const agentsToHide = 
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-color="30"'))
    .reduce((agents, el) => {
      const agentId = el.getAttribute("data-agentid")
      if (!agents.includes(agentId)) agents.push(agentId)
      return agents
    }, [])
    .forEach(agentId => {
      document.querySelectorAll(`[data-agent-id="${agentId}"]`)
        .forEach(el => {
          el.style.display = "none"
        })
    })
```

```html
<div class="sch" data-agent-id=1>Agent 1</div>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30">30</div>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30">30</div>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="20">20</div>
<div class="sch" data-agent-id=2>Agent 2</div>
<div data-agentid="2" data-color="10">10</div>
<div data-agentid="2" data-color="20">20</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately I can not use this method. I updated what the code contained.

Answer (score -1):

Plain and simple in vanilla javascript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-color="30"]').forEach(function(item) {
  item.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30">Test30</div>
<div data-agentid="2" data-color="20">Test20</div>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30">Test30</div>
<div data-agentid="2" data-color="20">Test20</div>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30">Test30</div>
<div data-agentid="2" data-color="20">Test20</div>
<div data-agentid="1" data-color="30">Test30</div>
```